# Python flask, apache and mod_wsgi application not working

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I am trying to build an application in python which can be run from XAMPP's Apache, therefore I installed flask (`$ pip install flask`) and I followed the following instructions for mod_wsgi installation http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html.
I am using Apache from XAMPP, version 2.4.29, and python 3.6.4 from anaconda. I built the mod_wsgi file (version 4.6.4) by downloading from  https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases and using the following command :

`$ ./configure --with-apxs=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apxs --with-python=/Users/pauline/anaconda3/bin/python3.6 --disable-framework`

followed by `make`and `sudo make install`. I also tried it with and without `--disable-framework`. After the installation, I checked `otool -L mod_wsgi.so` which gives me (looks correct):

`SCARLET10siMac4:modules pauline$ otool -L mod_wsgi.so
mod_wsgi.so:
@rpath/libpython3.6m.dylib (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 3.6.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1452.23.0)`

Also, when the Apache loaded modules is checked (by running this command: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -M`), it shows `wsgi_module (shared)` as well. And the output of `sys.prefix` is /Users/pauline/anaconda3 and of `sys.version` is 3.6.4

My application (image_download.py) has the simple following code :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Index Page'

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
   return 'Hello, World'

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

And my wsgi file (image_download.wsgi) the following :

```
 import sys
 sys.path.insert(0,"/Users/pauline/Documents/Code/platform_projects/image_download/image_download")
 from image_download import app as application
```

Finally, my http.conf virtual host part is :

```
 WSGIPythonHome /Users/pauline/anaconda3
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/Users/pauline/Documents/Code/platform_projects/image_download"
 ServerName imageDownload.localhost
 ServerAlias imageDownload.localhost
 WSGIDaemonProcess image_download user=daemon group=daemon threads=5     home=/Users/pauline/Documents/Code/platform_projects/image_download python-path=/Users/pauline/Documents/Code/platform_projects/image_download:/Users/pauline/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
 WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/pauline/Documents/Code/platform_projects/image_download/image_download.wsgi
 <Directory /Users/pauline/Documents/Code/platform_projects/image_download>
 WSGIProcessGroup image_download
 WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

When I run my application as a localhost, it gives me an **Server error! Error 500** and when I check the apache error log, it says the following:

```
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865] mod_wsgi (pid=6011): Target WSGI script '/Users/pauline/Documents/Code/platform_projects/image_download/image_download.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865] mod_wsgi (pid=6011): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/Users/pauline/Documents/Code/platform_projects/image_download/image_download.wsgi'. 
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865] Traceback (most recent call last):
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]   File "/Users/pauline/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 27, in <module>
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]     from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]   File "/Users/pauline/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 2585, in <module>
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]     from _scproxy import _get_proxy_settings, _get_proxies
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865] ImportError: dlopen(/Users/pauline/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_scproxy.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]   Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]   Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]  in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865] 
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865] 
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865] Traceback (most recent call last):
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]   File "/Users/pauline/Documents/Code/platform_projects/image_download/image_download.wsgi", line 13, in <module>
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]     from image_download import app as application
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]   File "/Users/pauline/Documents/Code/platform_projects/image_download/image_download.py", line 9, in <module>
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]     from flask import Flask
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]   File "/Users/pauline/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]     from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]   File "/Users/pauline/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]     __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]   File "/Users/pauline/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]     from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]   File "/Users/pauline/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 27, in <module>
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]     from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES, \\
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]   File "/Users/pauline/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 30, in <module>
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865]     from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header, \\
 [wsgi:error] [pid 6011] [remote ::1:50865] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
```

When I run the program via Flask, it runs completely fine. However, when running it via apache localhost, it shows server error. Therefore, I mostly suspect that the problem is coming from wrong installation of `mod_wsgi.so`, however, I cannot be able to debug it, although installation steps (mentioned above) were seem to be correct.

Comment: Are you loading PHP module into Apache as well? Anaconda Python ships with its own versions of a lot of libraries. If you have PHP also loaded, it may be importing system versions of libraries and these are taking precedence over those from the Python distribution and so Python packages built against Python distro versions will fail.

Comment: I could also suggest not using configure/make/make install installation method for mod_wsgi. Use ``pip install`` method as described in https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/ Once installed, use ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` to generate the config you should add to Apache to load the mod_wsgi module. It should generate a ``LoadFile`` directive to ensure Anaconda Python library loaded correctly.

Comment: I tried out the second way by using the `pip install` method and got exactly the same errors. Indeed the PHP modules are loaded from Apache as well, what could I do instead ?

Comment: Actually, it may not be PHP, but XAMPP itself. What do you get for ``ls -las /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib``?

Comment: Can you not use ``XAMPP`` distribution? It is the cause of the problems here are isn't going to work with Anaconda Python or even System Python when using mod_wsgi. Their shipping of their own libraries for everything is going to cause conflicts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your good suggestions. I wanted to try building mod_wsgi with Anaconda Python and system Apache but as I am working on MacOs X Sierra I cannot find the corresponding apxs file. Do you know how to handle that ?

Comment: You need to use the ``pip install mod_wsgi`` method on macOS. See https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/

Answer (score 0):

The output of `ls -las /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib` is the following :

```
    0 drwxr-xr-x  273 root  admin      9282 Feb  6 17:18 .
    0 drwxrwxr-x   38 root  admin      1292 Apr 23 10:29 ..
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin         8 Feb  6 17:18 VERSION
    0 drwxr-xr-x   14 root  admin       476 Feb  6 17:18 apr-util-1
   24 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      9278 Jan 17 01:24 apr.exp
   16 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      5549 Jan 17 01:24 aprutil.exp
 5632 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin   2879936 Jan 17 01:22 c-client.a
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin       637 Jan 17 01:10 charset.alias
    0 drwxr-xr-x    3 root  admin       102 Feb  6 17:17 cmake
    0 drwxr-xr-x   14 root  admin       476 Feb  6 17:17 engines
    0 drwxr-xr-x    6 root  admin       204 Feb  6 17:17 gettext
    0 drwxr-xr-x    6 root  admin       204 Feb  6 17:18 icu
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        24 Feb  6 17:18 instantclient -> instantclient-11.2.0.3.0
    0 drwxr-xr-x   29 root  admin       986 Feb  6 17:18 instantclient-11.2.0.3.0
  432 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    218856 Jan 17 01:24 libapr-1.0.dylib
  640 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    323944 Jan 17 01:24 libapr-1.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        16 Feb  6 17:18 libapr-1.dylib -> libapr-1.0.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1016 Jan 17 01:24 libapr-1.la
  128 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     64604 Jan 17 03:22 libapreq2.3.7.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libapreq2.3.dylib -> libapreq2.3.7.1.dylib
  152 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin     75992 Jan 17 03:22 libapreq2.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libapreq2.dylib -> libapreq2.3.7.1.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1127 Jan 17 03:22 libapreq2.la
  352 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    178408 Jan 17 01:24 libaprutil-1.0.dylib
  488 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    248320 Jan 17 01:24 libaprutil-1.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        20 Feb  6 17:18 libaprutil-1.dylib -> libaprutil-1.0.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1181 Jan 17 01:24 libaprutil-1.la
   24 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      9716 Jan 17 01:10 libasprintf.0.dylib
   16 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      5256 Jan 17 01:10 libasprintf.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        19 Feb  6 17:18 libasprintf.dylib -> libasprintf.0.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       993 Jan 17 01:10 libasprintf.la
  152 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     73884 Jan 17 01:15 libbz2.1.0.6.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        18 Feb  6 17:18 libbz2.1.0.dylib -> libbz2.1.0.6.dylib
  392 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    198264 Jan 17 01:15 libbz2.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        18 Feb  6 17:18 libbz2.dylib -> libbz2.1.0.6.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        10 Feb  6 17:18 libc-client.a -> c-client.a
   24 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      9176 Jan 17 01:07 libcharset.1.dylib
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      3848 Jan 17 01:07 libcharset.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        18 Feb  6 17:18 libcharset.dylib -> libcharset.1.dylib
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin       983 Jan 17 01:07 libcharset.la
 4352 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin   2225252 Jan 17 01:19 libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
 6952 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin   3557720 Jan 17 01:19 libcrypto.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libcrypto.dylib -> libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  744 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    378648 Jan 17 01:29 libct.4.dylib
 1064 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    541464 Jan 17 01:29 libct.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        13 Feb  6 17:18 libct.dylib -> libct.4.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1038 Jan 17 01:29 libct.la
  928 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    471072 Jan 17 01:22 libcurl.4.dylib
 1368 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    699384 Jan 17 01:22 libcurl.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libcurl.dylib -> libcurl.4.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1146 Jan 17 01:22 libcurl.la
  392 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    197976 Jan 17 01:22 libexpat.1.5.2.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        20 Feb  6 17:18 libexpat.1.dylib -> libexpat.1.5.2.dylib
  440 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    224560 Jan 17 01:22 libexpat.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        20 Feb  6 17:18 libexpat.dylib -> libexpat.1.5.2.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       868 Jan 17 01:22 libexpat.la
  176 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     88448 Jan 17 01:23 libexslt.0.dylib
  216 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    108784 Jan 17 01:23 libexslt.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        16 Feb  6 17:18 libexslt.dylib -> libexslt.0.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1163 Jan 17 01:23 libexslt.la
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      1472 Jan 17 01:14 libfl.a
  152 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     76976 Jan 17 03:19 libform.5.dylib
  232 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    115440 Jan 17 03:19 libform.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libform.dylib -> libform.5.dylib
 1152 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    586624 Jan 17 03:19 libform_g.a
 1336 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    681372 Jan 17 01:16 libfreetype.6.dylib
 1632 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    833640 Jan 17 01:16 libfreetype.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        19 Feb  6 17:18 libfreetype.dylib -> libfreetype.6.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1000 Jan 17 01:16 libfreetype.la
  552 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    279420 Jan 17 01:16 libgd.2.0.0.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        17 Feb  6 17:18 libgd.2.dylib -> libgd.2.0.0.dylib
  632 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    322120 Jan 17 01:16 libgd.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        17 Feb  6 17:18 libgd.dylib -> libgd.2.0.0.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1082 Jan 17 01:16 libgd.la
   56 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     27700 Jan 17 03:03 libgdbm.3.0.0.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        19 Feb  6 17:18 libgdbm.3.dylib -> libgdbm.3.0.0.dylib
   72 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin     36312 Jan 17 03:03 libgdbm.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        19 Feb  6 17:18 libgdbm.dylib -> libgdbm.3.0.0.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       737 Jan 17 03:03 libgdbm.la
 1704 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    872004 Jan 17 01:10 libgettextlib-0.18.1.dylib
 2248 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin   1149000 Jan 17 01:10 libgettextlib.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        26 Feb  6 17:18 libgettextlib.dylib -> libgettextlib-0.18.1.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1166 Jan 17 01:10 libgettextlib.la
  648 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    328412 Jan 17 01:10 libgettextpo.0.dylib
  992 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    505072 Jan 17 01:10 libgettextpo.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        20 Feb  6 17:18 libgettextpo.dylib -> libgettextpo.0.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1133 Jan 17 01:10 libgettextpo.la
  552 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    282404 Jan 17 01:10 libgettextsrc-0.18.1.dylib
  808 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    410824 Jan 17 01:10 libgettextsrc.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        26 Feb  6 17:18 libgettextsrc.dylib -> libgettextsrc-0.18.1.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1218 Jan 17 01:10 libgettextsrc.la
 1912 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    977048 Jan 17 01:07 libiconv.2.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        16 Feb  6 17:18 libiconv.dylib -> libiconv.2.dylib
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin       961 Jan 17 01:07 libiconv.la
35712 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin  18280536 Jan 17 01:29 libicudata.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 libicudata.48.dylib -> libicudata.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 libicudata.dylib -> libicudata.48.1.1.dylib
 4472 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin   2286488 Jan 17 01:29 libicui18n.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 libicui18n.48.dylib -> libicui18n.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 libicui18n.dylib -> libicui18n.48.1.1.dylib
  112 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     55384 Jan 17 01:29 libicuio.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libicuio.48.dylib -> libicuio.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libicuio.dylib -> libicuio.48.1.1.dylib
  536 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    270572 Jan 17 01:29 libicule.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libicule.48.dylib -> libicule.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libicule.dylib -> libicule.48.1.1.dylib
  112 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     53944 Jan 17 01:29 libiculx.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libiculx.48.dylib -> libiculx.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libiculx.dylib -> libiculx.48.1.1.dylib
  136 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     68560 Jan 17 01:29 libicutest.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 libicutest.48.dylib -> libicutest.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 libicutest.dylib -> libicutest.48.1.1.dylib
  312 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    157120 Jan 17 01:29 libicutu.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libicutu.48.dylib -> libicutu.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libicutu.dylib -> libicutu.48.1.1.dylib
 3032 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin   1552160 Jan 17 01:29 libicuuc.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libicuuc.48.dylib -> libicuuc.48.1.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libicuuc.dylib -> libicuuc.48.1.1.dylib
  120 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin     58192 Jan 17 01:10 libintl.8.dylib
  160 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin     81504 Jan 17 01:10 libintl.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libintl.dylib -> libintl.8.dylib
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      1057 Jan 17 01:10 libintl.la
  576 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    291624 Jan 17 01:15 libjpeg.8.dylib
  688 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    348544 Jan 17 01:15 libjpeg.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libjpeg.dylib -> libjpeg.8.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       968 Jan 17 01:15 libjpeg.la
  144 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin     69848 Jan 17 01:20 liblber-2.4.2.5.4.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 liblber-2.4.2.dylib -> liblber-2.4.2.5.4.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 liblber.dylib -> liblber-2.4.2.5.4.dylib
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin       915 Jan 17 01:21 liblber.la
  632 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    321228 Jan 17 01:21 libldap-2.4.2.5.4.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 libldap-2.4.2.dylib -> libldap-2.4.2.5.4.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 libldap.dylib -> libldap-2.4.2.5.4.dylib
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin       984 Jan 17 01:21 libldap.la
  680 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    347212 Jan 17 01:21 libldap_r-2.4.2.5.4.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        25 Feb  6 17:18 libldap_r-2.4.2.dylib -> libldap_r-2.4.2.5.4.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        25 Feb  6 17:18 libldap_r.dylib -> libldap_r-2.4.2.5.4.dylib
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin       996 Jan 17 01:21 libldap_r.la
   72 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     33864 Jan 17 01:06 libltdl.3.1.0.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        19 Feb  6 17:18 libltdl.3.dylib -> libltdl.3.1.0.dylib
   72 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin     35792 Jan 17 01:06 libltdl.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        19 Feb  6 17:18 libltdl.dylib -> libltdl.3.1.0.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       903 Jan 17 01:06 libltdl.la
    0 drwxr-xr-x    2 root  admin        68 Feb  6 17:17 libmcrypt
  528 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    266900 Jan 17 01:21 libmcrypt.4.4.8.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libmcrypt.4.dylib -> libmcrypt.4.4.8.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libmcrypt.dylib -> libmcrypt.4.4.8.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       897 Jan 17 01:21 libmcrypt.la
   72 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     34372 Jan 17 03:19 libmenu.5.dylib
  104 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin     49896 Jan 17 03:19 libmenu.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libmenu.dylib -> libmenu.5.dylib
  584 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    296992 Jan 17 03:19 libmenu_g.a
  408 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    207980 Jan 17 03:24 libmhash.2.0.1.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        20 Feb  6 17:18 libmhash.2.dylib -> libmhash.2.0.1.dylib
  456 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    230920 Jan 17 03:24 libmhash.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        20 Feb  6 17:18 libmhash.dylib -> libmhash.2.0.1.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       884 Jan 17 03:24 libmhash.la
  992 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    506748 Jan 17 03:19 libming.1.dylib
 1520 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    775992 Jan 17 03:19 libming.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libming.dylib -> libming.1.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1122 Jan 17 03:19 libming.la
 7744 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin   3964748 Jan 17 03:01 libmysqlclient.18.dylib
18776 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin   9609408 Jan 17 03:01 libmysqlclient.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 libmysqlclient.dylib -> libmysqlclient.18.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        20 Feb  6 17:18 libmysqlclient_r.18.dylib -> libmysqlclient.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        16 Feb  6 17:18 libmysqlclient_r.a -> libmysqlclient.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        20 Feb  6 17:18 libmysqlclient_r.dylib -> libmysqlclient.dylib
   88 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin     43928 Jan 17 03:01 libmysqlservices.a
  272 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    135528 Jan 17 03:20 libncurses++.a
  632 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    322584 Jan 17 03:19 libncurses.5.dylib
 1048 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    533552 Jan 17 03:19 libncurses.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        18 Feb  6 17:18 libncurses.dylib -> libncurses.5.dylib
 4512 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin   2309112 Jan 17 03:19 libncurses_g.a
  360 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    181020 Jan 17 01:25 libnghttp2.14.dylib
  520 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    263784 Jan 17 01:25 libnghttp2.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        19 Feb  6 17:18 libnghttp2.dylib -> libnghttp2.14.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1036 Jan 17 01:25 libnghttp2.la
   32 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     13508 Jan 17 03:19 libpanel.5.dylib
   32 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin     16320 Jan 17 03:19 libpanel.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        16 Feb  6 17:18 libpanel.dylib -> libpanel.5.dylib
  200 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin     98784 Jan 17 03:19 libpanel_g.a
  576 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    292028 Jan 17 01:07 libpcre.1.dylib
  608 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    308592 Jan 17 01:07 libpcre.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libpcre.dylib -> libpcre.1.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       966 Jan 17 01:07 libpcre.la
   24 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      8948 Jan 17 01:07 libpcreposix.0.dylib
   16 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      4432 Jan 17 01:07 libpcreposix.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        20 Feb  6 17:18 libpcreposix.dylib -> libpcreposix.0.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1042 Jan 17 01:07 libpcreposix.la
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        10 Feb  6 17:18 libpng.a -> libpng15.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        14 Feb  6 17:18 libpng.dylib -> libpng15.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        11 Feb  6 17:18 libpng.la -> libpng15.la
  384 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    193508 Jan 17 01:15 libpng15.15.dylib
  520 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    265128 Jan 17 01:15 libpng15.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        17 Feb  6 17:18 libpng15.dylib -> libpng15.15.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       980 Jan 17 01:15 libpng15.la
  360 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    182820 Jan 17 01:32 libpq.5.5.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libpq.5.dylib -> libpq.5.5.dylib
  512 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    259176 Jan 17 01:32 libpq.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libpq.dylib -> libpq.5.5.dylib
 1912 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    976728 Jan 17 03:03 libsablot.0.100.3.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 libsablot.0.dylib -> libsablot.0.100.3.dylib
 2776 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin   1419176 Jan 17 03:03 libsablot.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        23 Feb  6 17:18 libsablot.dylib -> libsablot.0.100.3.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       912 Jan 17 03:03 libsablot.la
  848 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    430984 Jan 17 03:49 libsqlite.0.8.6.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libsqlite.0.dylib -> libsqlite.0.8.6.dylib
 1160 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    590648 Jan 17 03:49 libsqlite.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        21 Feb  6 17:18 libsqlite.dylib -> libsqlite.0.8.6.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       887 Jan 17 03:49 libsqlite.la
 2448 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin   1251080 Jan 17 01:31 libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        22 Feb  6 17:18 libsqlite3.0.dylib -> libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib
 2864 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin   1462768 Jan 17 01:31 libsqlite3.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        22 Feb  6 17:18 libsqlite3.dylib -> libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       915 Jan 17 01:31 libsqlite3.la
  928 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    471064 Jan 17 01:19 libssl.1.0.0.dylib
 1232 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    626736 Jan 17 01:19 libssl.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        18 Feb  6 17:18 libssl.dylib -> libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  896 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    458128 Jan 17 01:29 libsybdb.5.dylib
 1256 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    642648 Jan 17 01:29 libsybdb.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        16 Feb  6 17:18 libsybdb.dylib -> libsybdb.5.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1056 Jan 17 01:29 libsybdb.la
  848 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    431448 Jan 17 01:29 libtdsodbc.0.so
 1200 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    612936 Jan 17 01:29 libtdsodbc.a
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1072 Jan 17 01:29 libtdsodbc.la
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libtdsodbc.so -> libtdsodbc.0.so
  832 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    423052 Jan 17 01:15 libtiff.5.dylib
 1056 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    540008 Jan 17 01:15 libtiff.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libtiff.dylib -> libtiff.5.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       975 Jan 17 01:15 libtiff.la
   32 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     14968 Jan 17 01:15 libtiffxx.5.dylib
   24 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      8648 Jan 17 01:15 libtiffxx.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        17 Feb  6 17:18 libtiffxx.dylib -> libtiffxx.5.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1033 Jan 17 01:15 libtiffxx.la
 3432 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin   1755940 Jan 17 01:23 libxml2.2.dylib
 4648 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin   2379096 Jan 17 01:23 libxml2.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libxml2.dylib -> libxml2.2.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1065 Jan 17 01:23 libxml2.la
    0 drwxr-xr-x    2 root  admin        68 Feb  6 17:17 libxslt-plugins
  504 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    254616 Jan 17 01:23 libxslt.1.dylib
  696 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    356296 Jan 17 01:23 libxslt.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        15 Feb  6 17:18 libxslt.dylib -> libxslt.1.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1111 Jan 17 01:23 libxslt.la
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      1808 Jan 17 01:14 liby.a
  184 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     91968 Jan 17 01:07 libz.1.2.8.dylib
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        16 Feb  6 17:18 libz.1.dylib -> libz.1.2.8.dylib
  216 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin    107520 Jan 17 01:07 libz.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        16 Feb  6 17:18 libz.dylib -> libz.1.2.8.dylib
   64 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     30332 Jan 17 03:23 libzzip-0.13.dylib
   72 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin     35248 Jan 17 03:23 libzzip.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        18 Feb  6 17:18 libzzip.dylib -> libzzip-0.13.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1014 Jan 17 03:23 libzzip.la
   32 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     13952 Jan 17 03:23 libzzipfseeko-0.13.dylib
   24 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      9176 Jan 17 03:23 libzzipfseeko.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        24 Feb  6 17:18 libzzipfseeko.dylib -> libzzipfseeko-0.13.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1050 Jan 17 03:23 libzzipfseeko.la
   40 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin     19692 Jan 17 03:23 libzzipmmapped-0.13.dylib
   40 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin     18960 Jan 17 03:23 libzzipmmapped.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        25 Feb  6 17:18 libzzipmmapped.dylib -> libzzipmmapped-0.13.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1056 Jan 17 03:23 libzzipmmapped.la
   24 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      9288 Jan 17 03:23 libzzipwrap-0.13.dylib
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      3648 Jan 17 03:23 libzzipwrap.a
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        22 Feb  6 17:18 libzzipwrap.dylib -> libzzipwrap-0.13.dylib
    8 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin      1084 Jan 17 03:23 libzzipwrap.la
    0 drwxr-xr-x    3 root  admin       102 Feb  6 17:17 mysql
    0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root  admin       136 Feb  6 17:17 perl5
    0 drwxr-xr-x   71 root  admin      2414 Feb  6 17:17 php
    0 drwxr-xr-x   33 root  admin      1122 Feb  6 17:18 pkgconfig
    0 drwxr-xr-x    2 root  admin        68 Feb  6 17:17 proftpd
    0 drwxr-xr-x    3 root  admin       102 Feb  6 17:17 python2.6
    8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        17 Feb  6 17:18 terminfo -> ../share/terminfo
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin       269 Jan 17 01:23 xml2Conf.sh
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root  admin       283 Jan 17 01:23 xsltConf.sh
```